# PHP mysql: how do I select records for today, or a particular day?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with a table on which I can't change the structure.... Now there is a varchar column which contains a timestamp. Now I need to select the records whose timestamp translates to the current date, or a specified date.

Any help?

Comment: What date format you are using

Comment: Can you paste a row with that column in there so we know what format is the timestamp formatted in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you shouldn't be storing date information in a mysql database with a `VARCHAR` field.  Rather use `DATETIME` that is what it is for.  I can only guess how you have stored your timestamp date in the database but I am going to assume it is the following format:

```
YYYY-mm-dd hh:mi:ss (ie '2011-04-15 09:23:55')
```

You now have to format your input which I am assuming is a time object or it is a string in the same format as the data in the database:

```
$yourdate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $input);
```

then construct your query

```
query = "select * from table where substring(datecol, 1, 10) = '$yourdate'";
```

execute this and you should be good

Answer (score 0):

Based on the format that you're storing the date as a string, use the [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to parse out the date. Then you can use it as a part of the `where` clause to query desired data.

Comment: This doesn't account for the timestamp

Comment: @Wes He doesnt have a timestamp - its a varchar that stores the timestamp. It could just be YYYY-MM-DD or MM-DD-YYYY based on his application's definition of a timestamp.

Comment: I can see based on the OP's bad post where you might assume he really has a date field.  When I see timestamp to me that means it is date plus time.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from table  where date(your_field)=CURDATE()
```

or specific date

```
select * from table where date(your_field)=DATE_FORMAT(2011-05-31 00:02:00, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: +1: I agree - why was this downvoted?  The OP lacks detail about the date, but this is otherwise correct.

Comment: Invalid SQL syntax.  It's minor (missing `WHERE`s), but worth mentioning.  And to some people, worth downvoting.  :)

Comment: Also, it can be quite inefficient.  The query will need to do a full table scan to find matching rows, regardless of whether the column is indexed or not.